# How to work around the fact that FacetGrid doesn't have a style parameter?

Tags: python, seaborn

I can't figure out how to vary both hue and style in a seaborn `FacetGrid` mapped to `lineplot`, and still end up with a legend. Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
# add variables "group" and "stim_order" to the fMRI dataset, for demo purposes
df = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
df['group'] = df['subject'].map(lambda subj: int(subj.lstrip('s')) % 2)
df['stim_order'] = df['subject'].map({subj: np.random.choice([0, 1])
                                      for subj in df['subject'].unique()})
```

The following would be ideal, but isn't implemented (`FacetGrid` has no "style" param):

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='region', col='event', hue='group', style='stim_order')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'timepoint', 'signal')
```

This next approach also doesn't work, because apparently kwargs passed to `FacetGrid.map()` cannot be references to columns in the data:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='region', col='event', hue='group')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'timepoint', 'signal', style='stim_order')
# fails with ValueError: Could not interpret input 'stim_order'
```

I can work around these limitations by not specifying "hue" when setting up the `FacetGrid`, and adding a new column "size" to the data, so that I can pass all the data-related parameters as positional args. But then I get no legend:

```
df['size'] = 1
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='region', col='event')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'timepoint', 'signal', 'group', 'size', 'stim_order')
```

[image: 2x2 seaborn FacetGrid figure]

Is there a way to get a plot like this, but that has a brief `legend_out` containing the `hue` and `style` mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `g.map_dataframe` instead of `g.map` and get the behaviour you wish.

Using your code would result in:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='region', col='event', hue='group')
g.map_dataframe(sns.lineplot, 'timepoint', 'signal', style='stim_order')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an approach that kinda works, but requires some tuning of the `subplots_adjust` and `bbox_to_anchor` numbers, in concert with the figure size:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
# add variables "group" and "stim_order" to the fMRI dataset, for demo purposes
df = sns.load_dataset('fmri')
df['group'] = df['subject'].map(lambda subj: int(subj.lstrip('s')) % 2)
df['stim_order'] = df['subject'].map({subj: np.random.choice([0, 1])
                                      for subj in df['subject'].unique()})

df['size'] = 1
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='region', col='event')
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'timepoint', 'signal', 'group', 'size', 'stim_order')

g.fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
g.axes[-1, -1].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1))
```

[image: seaborn 2x2 FacetGrid with legend]

However, it introduces an unnecessary legend element for "size" which shouldn't be there, since size isn't *really* mapped to anything (it's always 1 in the dataset, only mapped as a workaround).